# Big O Complexity Python, find out running time for input of size 'n'

Tags: python, time-complexity

For this functon, I am to select the most appropriate Big-O running time for input of size n:

```
def 2d_list(n):
    i = 0
    data = []
    while i < n:            
        data.append([i] * n)
        i += 1
    return data
```

The above function takes an integer as a parameter and creates a 2d list of integers. For example, the following code fragment:

```
print(2d_list(3))
produces

[[0, 0, 0], [1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 2]]
Select one:
```

a. O(n^3)

b. O(n)

c. O(n log n)

d. O(n^2)

e. O(log n)

I think the answer should be `d. 0(n^2)`. Is this right?

Comment: Yes, that is right indeed.

Comment: Basically, you loop `n` times, and each iteration of the loop uses does N amount of work `[i] * N` so yeah, classic quadratic algorithm

Comment: Your input size is not `n`; you have the *number* `n` as input, which requires `lg n` bits to represent.

Comment: So, is n supposed to represent the input `n` or the *size* of that input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number of times the while loop runs is linearly related to the size of `n`, and in each of these iterations, `[i]*n` creates a list and adds `i` to it `n` times, which is another iteration. One iteration nested inside another is `O(n^2)` time complexity.

Comment: `n` is the argument, not the input size.

Answer (score 1):

None of the given options is correct. Let's rewrite the function ever so slightly: we're only going to rename the parameter from `n` to `x`:

```
def 2d_list(x):
    i = 0
    data = []
    while i < x:            
        data.append([i] * x)
        i += 1
    return data
```

Now how many operations do we have? There are still O(x^2) operations: For each of the `x` values of `i`, we have to create a list with `x` elements.

But what's the input size `n`? That's the number of *bits* you need to represent the number `x`. The number `x` grows much faster than `n`: you can basically double the size of `x` without adding more than 1 bit to the input.

As a result, you have `n = log x`, or `x = 2**n`. This means the time complexity of your function is actually `O(4**n)`.

Comment: it is O(2^n^2) not O(4^n)

Comment: `(2**n)**2 == 2**(n*2)`, not `2**(n**2)`. Exponentiation is not associative.

Comment: ok. my bad. Thank you

Answer (score -1):

The question is misleading. The input size is `log n` i.e. the number of bits required to represent `n`.

If we want to compute the complexity in terms of `n` instead of input size, then the answer is `O(n^2)`

If we want to compute in terms of input size `s`, then the answer is `O((2^s)^2) = O(2^(2*s)) = O((2^2)^s)`, as chepner wrote.

Comment: Isn't that what chepner already wrote?

Comment: sorry, my answer was wrong. corrected it now, after discussion with chepner. now it's the same.